# Credit information from uploaded image

Tags: file-uploads, image, file-manager

How can I pull back the {description} information from an uploaded image. Bearing in mind I'm pulling back an image manipulation of the original?

```
   <img src="{recipe-thumbnail:small}" alt="{description}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a tag pair for your image:

```
{recipe-thumbnail}
<img src="{url:small}" alt="{description}"/>
{/recipe-thumbnail}
```

You have a number of variables that can be used inside the tag such as:

{title}
{description}
{location}
{credit}

See for the full list https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/custom_fields.html#variable-pair-usage

Comment: You're right, thank you Bluedreamer completely forgot about it needing to be inside a tag pair.